# How to upload multiple images to a webservice?

Tags: android, web-services

I have done a single image upload to a web service using:

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
envelope.dotNet = true;
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

The webservice accepts a base64 encoded string as argument.
I want to upload multiple images to web service. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to upload multiple images to webservice

=> Simple enough, as you are done with uploading single image to web, you can try uploading multiple images in a loop.

But here you just need to create a separate webservice for catching images one by one and sending response to the Android client for the same. Once you are done with uploading all the images, make a call to your main webservice with Image IDs.

Otherwise, there is no possibility to send multi images in a single call, if you do so then get ready for the `OutOfMemoryError` exception.

Comment: yes I am getting OutOfMemoryError exception.Number of images is not fixed.could u be elaborate on creating webservice for catching images one by one